# On getting beyond LSB in discrete log

Tags: cryptanalysis, diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, elgamal-encryption, group-theory

In discrete log we employ sophie germain primes $p=2q+1$ where $q$ is a prime.

Then we know least significant bit $x_0$ in $$g^{2x+x_0}=h\bmod p$$ where $2x+x_0$ is discrete logarithm of known $h\bmod p$ with respect to known generator $g$.

1. Suppose $g^2=r\bmod p$ then why cannot I reduce the problem to $$r^{x}=hg^{-x_0}\bmod p$$ and let $x=2x'+x'_{0}$ where $x'_0$ is lsb of $x$ and recursive solve the problem of finding $2x+x_0$ which is discrete log of $h\bmod p$ with respect to generator $g$?
2. Suppose I know $x_0$ in $g^{3x+x_0}=h\bmod p$ where $x_0\in\{0,1,2\}$ holds (that is if it were easy to solve for the last ternary digit of discrete logarithm when $p=2q+1$ would the problem be any easier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If $p = 2q+1$ where $q$ is prime, and then we can efficiently solve for $x_0 \in \{0, 1\}$ for $g^{2x+x_0} = h \pmod p$, if $g$ is a generator.

This is true; this is a special case of the observation "if $g$ has order $a \times b$ with $b$ small, then if $g^y = h$, then we can find $y \bmod b$ quickly (specifically, in $O(\sqrt{b})$ time).

As $g$ is a generator for the entire group, it has order $2q$, and so we can find $y \bmod 2$ quickly (or, as you put it, find $x_0$ where $y = 2x + x_0$)

> Suppose $g^2 = r$, then why cannot I reduce the problem to $r^x = hg^{-x_0} \pmod p$

Well, I suppose you could, but solving that would be as difficult as the DLog problem (actually, that's provable; given an Oracle to do that, you can solve the entire DLog problem).  The previous observation doesn't help you solve this problem; $r$ has order $q$, which is a prime; it doesn't provide any magic ways to compute $x \bmod 2$; the best it can do is find $x \bmod q$ in $O(\sqrt{q})$ time, and we have more efficient ways than that.

> Suppose I know $x_0$ in $g^{3x+x_0} = h \pmod p$, which $x \in \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$, would that help.

Yes, if you had an Oracle that could find $y \bmod 3$, then you could efficiently solve the DLog problem.  That said, we don't know any way to do that efficiently (assuming that the order of the group wasn't a multiple of 3).

Comment: I do not see how to solve DLog if you know how to fine $y\bmod 3$. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: @Turbo: well, you would find $y \bmod 3$, and then compute $h' = (h g^{-(y \bmod 3)})^{3^{-1} \bmod q} = g^{\lfloor y/3\rfloor}$ ($q$ is the size of the group).  Then, giving $h'$ to the Oracle will give the next ternary digit, and repeat until you've read the entire value of $y$ in ternary.

Comment: you mean $\bmod (p-1)$ instead of $\bmod (q-1)$?

Comment: @Turbo: I mean the size of the group; I tried to edit it to be $p-1$, but the 5 minutes edit limit had passed...

Comment: are there discrete logarithm schemes where even the last bit is secure? Or is that bit always insecure?

Comment: @Turbo: yes, if the order of $g$ is a large prime, then given $g^x$, then no one can directly deduce the value of any bit of $g$.  In the above example ($p, (p-1)/2$ both prime), take $g$ to be any quadratic residue (other than 1)...

Comment: if $p,\phi(p)/2$ are both large primes and $g\neq1$ is a qr mod $p$ why is least significant bit hard?

Comment: @Turbo: the lsbit is hard because, with an oracle that, given $g^y \bmod p$ gives you the lsbit of $y$, you can recover the entire value of $y$.  The logic is the same as in the $\bmod 3$ case; you'd compute $h' = (hg^{-(y \bmod 2)})^{2^{-1} \bmod q} = g^{\lfloor y/2 \rfloor}$ to get the next bit.  This works because the size of the subgroup $q = (p-1)/2$ is odd, and so $2^{-1} \bmod q$ exists.

Comment: So supposing $r^2\equiv h\bmod p$ where $r$ has order $q$ and $p=2q+1$ then $h$ has exactly one 'square root' which is $r$ which can be found by $h^{2^{-1}}\bmod p$ since $2$ is invertible in exponent? Is there a second root which is $-r$ and is $r$ the principal root?

Comment: @1.. Yes, there is a second squareroot $-r$, however it is not a quadratic residue, and so does not have order $q$.

Comment: If $h'$ is a quadratic residue then $h'^{q}\equiv1\bmod p$. Isn't $-h'$ also a quadratic residue? For example $6\bmod10$ is qr since $4^2\equiv 6\bmod 10$ and notice $2^2\equiv4\equiv-6\bmod10$. So both $h'$ and $-h'$ can be qr's. How can $-h'$ be odd order if $h'$ is odd order? Another example is $4\equiv-9\bmod 13$ and $2^2\equiv 4\bmod 13$ and $3^2\equiv9\equiv -4\bmod 13$. So both $h'$ and $-h'$ are qr's if and only if $q$ is even in $p=2q+1$ ('only if' clear)?

Comment: @1.. This is correct; $h'$ and $-h'$ will not both be qr's if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.  When you state $p = 2q+1$, I presumed $q$ was prime (as stated in the question), and most primes are not even.